# Equality of mixed directional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and let $f$ be $C^2$ for any vectors $u,v$.

Prove that $dudv\ f = dvdu\ f$ where $du$ and $dv$ are directional derivatives.

I'm not really sure how to start on this, but thinking that it will be helpful to use the equality of mixed partial derivatives to show this.  I'd really appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We start here:

$$v(f)=\sum _{i=1}^n v_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$$

$$w(g)=\sum _{j=1}^n w_j\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^j}$$

With $g=v(f)$ plugged in:

$$w(v(f))=\sum _{j=1}^n w_j\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}v(f)$$
$$=\sum _{j=1}^n w_j\frac{\partial }{\partial x^j}\left(\sum _{i=1}^n v_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\right)$$

$$=\sum _{i,j=1}^n \left(w_jv_i\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^j\partial x^i}\right)$$.

All sums are finit, one can switch summation-order.
Don't forget, $f$ is vector-valued!
Partial derivations are applied to vector-function.
By a theorem of Schwarz, one can change order of differentiation,
$C^2$-mapping.